# Иносказание внутри прямой речи - нужно ли дублировать кавычки

Tags: пунктуация

Если в предложении

> "Знаю я ваше быстро!" - сказал Барбос: "Уехали на день, а пропали на неделю".

`быстро` служит для передачи иронии, следует ли взять его в кавычки?

Answer (score 1):

«Знаю я ваше "быстро"! — сказал Барбос. — Уехали на день, а пропали на неделю».
Розенталь §135, 121.

Answer (score -1):

Я не совсем уверен, насколько свод сложившихся практик правописания, связанных с вложенными кавычками можно назвать правилами, но устоявшиеся практики следующие:

Если есть возможность добавить визуально другие кавычки, их можно вкладывать - в вашем случае, например, можно написать так:

> "Знаю я ваше «быстро!»", — сказал Барбос.

Если же такой возможности нет (например, нет такой литеры в типографском наборе или данный компьютерный шрифт имеет только один вид кавычек), то можно использовать те же самые кавычки но только в случае если они не следуют подряд, то есть так вот нельзя:

> "Знаю я ваше "быстро!"", — сказал Барбос.

В этом случае вместо двух кавычек обычно пишется одна:

> "Знаю я ваше "быстро!" — сказал Барбос.

Ещё я вот что хочу заметить - я привёл примеры намеренно усечённые, потому что, строго говоря, в вашем случае кавычки в принципе не нужны, у Розенталя читаем:

> Если на месте «разрыва» прямой речи словами автора должна была бы
>   стоять точка, то перед этими словами ставятся запятая и тире, а после
>   них — точка и тире, причем вторая часть прямой речи пишется с
>   прописной буквы

В вашем случае, стало быть, будет так:

"Знаю я ваше "быстро!", — сказал Барбос. — Уехали на день, а пропали на неделю".

(обращаю ваше внимание, что не только кавычек не нужно, но и двоеточия тоже, вместо него - точка с тире).

Ну и, наконец, самое последнее, лично я бы не ставил вокруг быстро кавычек совсем.

Comment: *Ну и, наконец, самое последнее, лично я бы не ставил вокруг быстро кавычек совсем.* - вот самое главное надо вперед вынести (сразу представил себе какие-нибудь "12 стульев в современной адаптации" c кавычками и смайликами в каждом предложении).

Comment: сложившаяся типографская практика обратная, лапки вкладываются в елочки: «знаю я ваше „быстро“»

Comment: @NikolayErshov ваша правда, это дельное замечание, я всего лишь хотел показать два разных типа кавычек